# What is the locus of the given question?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, locus

I'm attempting to solve the following problem:

What geometric figure is formed by the locus of a point which moves so that the sum of four times its distance from the x-axis and nine times its distance from the y-axis  is equal to 10?

My attempt:

[image: attempt]

From the diagram, I conclude that locus will be a circle.

Is my answer correct or does it contain mistakes? What is the correct solution?

Comment: “[the] sum of four times its distance from $x$-axis and nine times its distance from the $y$-axis is equal to 10” —This is an equation written out in words.  Just translate it into symbols.

Comment: Distance from x-axis is the y-coordinate. So the answer should be..?

Comment: im not getting@samjoe  how can u  write  4y +  9x

Answer (score 3):

The distance of a point $P(x,y)$ from axis is $|x|$ and $|y|$

Therefore the locus you are looking for has equation 
$$4|x|+9|y|=10$$
which graphically is a rhombus having as sides the lines

$4x+9y=10;\;4x-9y=10;\;4x+y=-10;\;4x-9y=-10$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If we call the coordinate of the point is $(x,y)$ then $x$ and $y$ have to satisfy the equation: $4 \mid y \mid +9 \mid x \mid =10$. Now, consider the equation on each quadrant of the $xy$-plane. For instance, on the first quadrant, where $x$ and $y$ are positive, the equation is $4y+9x=10$.

Comment: thanks,,,,@HuyQuoc dang